# Need help ranking columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the most votes according by their country, city, and institute. 
However, Im getting the wrong output.

My Code:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.country, u.city, u.institute, uv.up_vote, uv.down_vote,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY SUM(uv.up_vote) + SUM(uv.down_vote) DESC) country_rank,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY SUM(uv.up_vote) + SUM(uv.down_vote) DESC) city_rank,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY institute ORDER BY SUM(uv.up_vote) + SUM(uv.down_vote) DESC) institute_rank
    FROM Users u LEFT JOIN users_vote uv ON u.user_id=uv.receiver_id
    GROUP BY u.user_id, u.country, u.city, u.institute, uv.up_vote, uv.down_vote;
```

My output:

```
user_id | country |     city      |        institute         | up_vote | down_vote | country_rank | city_rank | institute_rank
---------+---------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------
      18 | Canada  | Ottawa        | University of Ottawa     |         |           |            1 |         1 |              1
      20 | Canada  | Ottawa        | University of Ottawa     |         |           |            1 |         1 |              1
      17 | Canada  | Toronto       | University of Ottawa     |      10 |         0 |            3 |         1 |              3
      26 | USA     | Santa Clara   | UCSD                     |         |           |            1 |         1 |              1
      25 | USA     | Seattle       | University of Washington |         |           |            1 |         1 |              1
      27 | USA     | Los Angeles   | UCLA                     |         |           |            1 |         1 |              1
      22 | USA     | New York      | NYU                      |         |           |            1 |         1 |              1
      21 | USA     | San Francisco | CalTech                  |         |           |            1 |         1 |              1
      23 | USA     | Texas         | University of Texas      |      10 |         0 |            6 |         1 |              1
      16 | test123 | test123       | test123                  |         |           |            1 |         1 |              1
```

What I want my output to be

```
user_id | country |     city      |        institute         | up_vote | down_vote | country_rank | city_rank | institute_rank
---------+---------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------
      18 | Canada  | Ottawa        | University of Ottawa     |         |           |            2 |         1 |              2
      20 | Canada  | Ottawa        | University of Ottawa     |         |           |            2 |         1 |              2
      17 | Canada  | Toronto       | University of Ottawa     |      10 |         0 |            1 |         1 |              1
      26 | USA     | Santa Clara   | UCSD                     |         |           |            2 |         1 |              1
      25 | USA     | Seattle       | University of Washington |         |           |            2 |         1 |              1
      27 | USA     | Los Angeles   | UCLA                     |         |           |            2 |         1 |              1
      22 | USA     | New York      | NYU                      |         |           |            2 |         1 |              1
      21 | USA     | San Francisco | CalTech                  |         |           |            2 |         1 |              1
      23 | USA     | Texas         | University of Texas      |      10 |         0 |            1 |         1 |              1
      16 | test123 | test123       | test123                  |         |           |            2 |         1 |              1
```

TABLE users_vote

```
 receiver_id | up_vote | down_vote
-------------+---------+-----------
          23 |      10 |         0
          17 |      10 |         0
          17 |      10 |         0
```

Im using postgresql Thanks!

Comment: Please explain your logic for the three ranking columns.  It is not obvious.  And CalTech is in Pasadena in southern California, not in San Francisco.  You may have offended the entire state of CA with that one ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I want to ((SUM all the columns in users_vote table in up_vote column)  + (SUM all the columns in users_vote table in down_vote column)) = total_votes and rank according to my total votes. I added the users_vote table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three points:

1. If you want to rank nulls last, you should say so in the `ORDER BY` clauses.
2. And I suppose you want to *subtract* downvotes from upvotes?
3. At last I suppose you want one row per user_id, so this should be the `GROUP BY` key.

The query:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.country, u.city, u.institute, uv.up_vote, uv.down_vote,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country
               ORDER BY SUM(uv.up_vote) - SUM(uv.down_vote) DESC NULLS LAST
              ) AS country_rank,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY city
               ORDER BY SUM(uv.up_vote) - SUM(uv.down_vote) DESC NULLS LAST
              ) AS city_rank,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY institute
               ORDER BY SUM(uv.up_vote) - SUM(uv.down_vote) DESC NULLS LAST
              ) AS institute_rank
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN users_vote uv ON u.user_id = uv.receiver_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY u.user_id;
```

<sub>(Some DBMS require `u.country, u.city, u.institute` to be in the `GROUP BY` clause, too, but this is not required by the SQL standard, because these columns are functionally dependent on `u.user_id`, which I surmise is the table's key. I am pretty sure that PostgreSQL is standard compliant in this regard.)</sub>

Comment: Ahh I forgot about the nulls last. Thank you so much!